# "Stray timeout" - what does the empty timeout in javascript do?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm going thru some legacy code and I've noticed the following line(s):

```
// Stray timeout
var t = setTimeout('',1);
```

Does it do anything? Is it really required?

---

There is a following question on SO: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

> The solution is to "pause" the JavaScript execution to let the rendering threads catch up. And this is the effect that setTimeout() with a timeout of 0 does. It is like a thread/process yield in C. Although it seems to say "run this immediately" it actually gives the browser a chance to finish doing some none-JavaScript things that have been waiting to finish before attending to this new piece of JavaScript.

That explains benefits of executing a function in setTimeout. But how about executing an empty string?

Comment: GitHub flavored markdown doesn't work here.  You can't use the 3 backticks to indent code.

Comment: Is `t` used anywhere below?

Comment: @Bergi: Even if it was, this still wouldn't do anything?  Would it?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Some (most?) browsers use auto-incrementing timeout ids. You might do `while(t--) clearTimeout(t);` to kill all outstanding ones.

Comment: @Bergi: That's... a theory.  I don't know why you'd do that, but it's a theory.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yeah. Though, as Matt has laid out in his answer, it wouldn't even work.

Answer (score 6):

```
setTimeout('',1)
```

This line does absolutely nothing.  You are telling JavaScript to `eval()` the string `''`.  That does nothing.

Sometimes doing this is useful, as it "pushes the code to the bottom of the stack" to run it after the function (and whatever UI updates the browser is doing) finishes.

For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // Work with some DOM elements, after the browser has a second to render them
}, 0);
```

But I can't see an empty string having any effect on anything.

EDIT: In Google Chrome, if you do `setTimeout('',1)` it doesn't return you anything.  Normally, it would return you the timeout_id, so you could cancel it with `clearTimeout`.  But, in Google Chrome, `setTimeout('',1)` returns `undefined`, which makes be believe it doesn't even set a timeout, since you didn't give it anything to do.  So, yeah, it *literally* does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Why a down-vote?  Am I wrong?  Does `setTimeout('',1)` (or `eval('')`) actually do anything?  I can't think of this actually having any effect (good or bad) on anything.

Comment: I have no idea why someone down voted this. It's a perfectly correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that it is a browser version test.

For example, in IE9,

```
setTimeout('',1)
```

returns `undefined`. However in IE10, it returns an integer. As Rocket Hazmat pointed out, which I also confirmed, Chrome 33 returns `undefined`.

Comment: This is possible, but what exactly is it testing for?  You got `undefined`... now what?  Is it Chrome?  IE9?  This is a good theory, though it's a bad way to implement a browser check.  +1 though for the theory.

Comment: Agreed, this would be quite an incomplete test if this were it. That's why I upvoted Bergi's question about how `t` is used.